# Counting how many IDs Report to a manager in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset that uses python and numpy in it, what I have is a dataset that looks at Employees and their managers. What I want is to count how many reports one manager has.

Here is the sample dataset:

```
ID     Date          Job          Dept.     Manager ID 
 1    Oct 2022     Sales Rep      Sales         5
 1    Dec 2022     Sales Rep      Sales         5
 1    Feb 2023     Sales Rep      Sales         5
 2    Feb 2022     Tech Support   Tech          4
 2    Jun 2022     Sales Advisor  Sales         5
 2    Nov 2022     Sales Advisor  Sales         5
 3    Dec 2021     Tech Consult   Tech          4 
 3    Sept 2022    Tech Advisor   Tech          4
```

The output I want is:

```
Manager ID    Reports
    4            1
    5            2
```

My current code I have used is :

```
counts = df['ID'].groupby(df['Manager ID'].astype(float)).nunique()
df['Reports'] = df['ID'].astype(str).map(counts).fillna(0, downcast ='infer')
```

This code only outputs zeros. Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> (df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Manager ID'])
       .groupby('Manager ID', as_index=False)
       .agg(Report=('ID', 'size')))

   Manager ID  Report
0           4       2
1           5       2
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you just need:

```
df.groupby('Manager ID')['ID'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
Manager ID
4    2
5    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
managers = df['Manager ID'].unique()
pd.DataFrame({
    'Manager ID': managers,
    'Reports': [df.loc[df['Manager ID'].eq(x), 'ID'].nunique() for x in managers]
})
```

Output:

```
   Manager ID  Reports
0           5        2
1           4        2
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you could just do

```
import collections
print(collections.Counter(df['Manager ID']))
```